# Replacing element of a string and of a list

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I'm here with few questions connected with replacing letters and elements of the string.
I did this using a new list and printing there * and letters using if. But I'm experimenting  with python so I will be really happy if someone could help me with this :)

1. Why this code doesn't work? I think that everything should be correct, but i got the same output and string wasn't changed.

```
    def find_a_common(list, string):
        for word in list:
            for letter in word:
                if letter in string:
                    string.replace(letter, "*")
        return string
    print(find_a_common(["ala"], "Kasia"))
```

2. Why this code doesn't work? I have similar example when everything is correct and the code works?

```
    def find_a_common(list, string):
        a = []
        for word in list:
            for letter in word:
                list = ["*" for letter in list if letter in string else letter for letter in list]
        return list
    print(find_a_common(["ala"], "Kasia"))
```

Example:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,1,3,2,1,1]
>>> [4 if x==1 else x for x in a]
[4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4]
```

3. Is there any possibility than triple loop works in this situation? How to build something like that.

```
    def find_a_common(list, string):
        for letter in string:
            for word in list:
                for letter in list:
                    if letter in list:
                        string.replace(letter, "*")
        return string
    print(find_a_common(["ala"], "Kasia"))
```

Comment: `str.replace` returns a new string. It does not change the string it is called on!

Comment: So, how to get the right output using this ?

Comment: `string = string.replace(letter, "*")`

Comment: what is that you want to achieve with 2 and 3? Could you please add examples with desired output?

Comment: Desire output is the same in 3 exercises. For example K*si*

Answer (score 0):

In Q1 line 5, Modify with this line

```
string=string.replace(letter, "*")
```